# Make an XML output with PHP from SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I am showing orders in a table from SQL. When a row or multiple rows are checked and submitted with a button (i also need a submit button) i want to generate an XML file.

```
$query = "SELECT SH.[Your Reference]
        ,SH.[Name]
        ,SIL.[Description]
        ,SIL.[Service Item Group Code]
        ,SIL.[Serial No_]
        ,SH.[Address]
        ,SH.[City]
        ,[No_]
        ,CASE SIL.[Claim] 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Ja' 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Nee'   END [Claim] 
        FROM  
        [dbo].[cache\$Service Header] SH INNER JOIN 
        [cache\$Service Item Line] SIL ON SH.[Document Type] = SIL.[document type] AND SH.[No_] = SIL.[Document No_] 
        WHERE [Repair Status Code] = '53'";

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params,$options);

if (!sqlsrv_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'No records found';
} else {
    ?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Garantie</th>
        <th>Serviceordernummer</th>
        <th>Referentie</th>
        <th>Serviceartikelgroepcode</th>
        <th>Omschrijving</th>
        <th>Serienummer</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Adres</th>
        <th>Plaats</th>
        <th>Ruilkaart</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo'<td>'.$row['Claim'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['No_'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Your Reference'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Service Item Group Code'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Serial No_'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Address'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['City'].'</td>'; 
    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ruilkaart\" class=\"radio\" value=\"ruilkaart\"></td>";
    echo'<tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php 
}
?>
```

The XML file must contain the following fields. I really don't know where to start. Is there anyone who can guide me trough this?

```
<xml xmlns="http://www.to-increase.com/data/blocks" contentnamespace="NAV">
<blocks>
<block id="Main">
<members>
       <member id="DocumentNo">485250</member>
       <member id="LineNo">10000</member>
       <member id="RepairStatusCodeIn">80</member>
       <member id="RepairStatusCodeOut">93</member>
       <member id="ServiceItemGroupCodeOut">7678</member>
       <member id="ItemNoOut">A010146</member>
       <member id="SerialNoOut">TEST2_SN</member>
       <member id="ExchangeReasonCode">D</member>
       <member id="ApprovalNumber">App_test</member>
       <member id="SectionCode">COMM: SET</member>
       <member id="DefectCode">COMM: 2</member>
       <member id="ResolutionCode">COMM: Z</member>
</members>
<blocks>
       <block id="ServiceItemLineOut">
                      <blocks>
                                      <block id="ServiceItemOut"/>
                                      <block id="ServiceLineOut"/>
                      </blocks>
       </block>
</blocks>
</block>
</blocks>
</xml>
```

@Sandip Patel

```
i followed the instructions. But somewhere i forgot something. Can't find the missing part. 

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End tag 'tblPortalStatus' does not match the start tag 'body'. Error processing resource 'http://PHP/Form...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?></tblPortalStatus>     
----------------------------------------^
```

My code is now:

```
if (!sqlsrv_num_rows($result)) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . sqlsrv_error());
}

if(sqlsrv_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {
         //$key holds the table column name
         $xml .= "<$key>";

         //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
         $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";

         //and close the element
         $xml .= "</$key>";
      }

      $xml.= "<".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}     

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";  
$root_element = "tblPortalStatus";

//close the root element
$xml .= "</tblPortalStatus>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;
```

Answer (score -1):

We decided to make a generate xml button and connect it to C# page where we export the XML files.